# Formulas which describe Electric power loss accurate

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

What formulas describe the real power loss in conductors the best?

I heard that there are different effects, like skin effect etc.

I want to calculate the % the power drops per meter distance.

Currently i have given: It is single-phase alternating current, the voltage is constant at 15kV, the temperature is outside so maybe 10 degree. The cross section is 120mm^2. But there might be more information i need.

The conductors are the [Overhead_line of the german railstadion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_line)

Comment: what is the frequency?

Answer (score 0):

The norm CEI 287 will give the method of assessment of the resistance of the conductor including the parameters you mentionned.

Basically, the method that is used (to my knowledge) is the ohmic losses formula with a corrected resistance due to skin and proximity effect.

About the skin effect, you can assume that the current is only flowing in an external ring in the conductor of depth : $$\delta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{10\rho}{\mu f}}$$

There are other methods...
Everything is listed in [this document](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ops-ecat.schneider-electric.com%2Fcut.CatalogueRetrieverServlet%2FCatalogueRetrieverServlet%3Ffct%3Dget_element%26env%3Dpublish%26scp_id%3DZ009%26el_typ%3Drendition%26cat_id%3DDESIGNER_RUSSIA%26maj_v%3D1%26min_v%3D8%26nod_id%3D0000000003%26doc_id%3DH383536%26frm%3Dpdf%26usg%3D%26dwnl%3Dtrue&ei=mh5_VIfkJ8jgaMD3gqAC&usg=AFQjCNGL6ukQNEMit04WNfeBSdCDYtJnmw&sig2=xiW9IldCmyr2DOFzg8BLRA).